# Consulta MYSQL com valores separados por mês e status

Tags: php, mysql

Senhores, estou quebrando a cabeça com uma consulta MYSQL onde deve ser retornado os seguintes dados:

**status de transação, mês e ano**

Exemplo:

**Mês 09/2021 -> 5 aguardando pagamento, 2 pagas e 10 cancelados**

**Mês 10/2021 -> 15 aguardando pagamento, 10 pagas e 3 cancelados**

Como posso fazer esta consulta?

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira, porém não me retorna os status_transacao

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE MONTH(vencimento) as mes, 
 COUNT(DISTINCT cod_transacao) as transacoes 
  FROM transacao 
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(vencimento, '%Y%m')
```

Se puder me ajudar, agraço muito.

Obrigado

Comment: olá Cristiano, consegue montar um exemplo com alguns dados pra ficar mais claro? pode ser no http://sqlfiddle.com/ ou no https://www.db-fiddle.com/ por exemplo

Comment: Olá @RicardoPontual, coloquei no SQLFIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b467ae/2 mas como pode ver ele só esta retornando um resultado por mês, mas preciso que seja retornado quantos pagamentos, cancelamentos ou pagamentos pendentes tiveram. Consegue me ajudar? Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente fazer uns testes utilizando o Case dentro do Count para fazer a contagem separada por status:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(vencimento) as mes,
    YEAR(vencimento) as ano,
    count(cod_transacao) as transacoes, 
    count(case when status_transacao = 'pending' then 1 end) as pendentes,
    count(case when status_transacao = 'pago' then 1 end) as pagas,
    count(case when status_transacao = 'canceled' then 1 end) as canceladas
FROM transacao 
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(vencimento),
    YEAR(vencimento)
```

Comment: Olá, @imex é isso mesmo, não sabia da utilização de Case dentro do Count, vou estudar sobre! Obrigado pela ajuda!